# Pass a table from controller to view - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, variable-assignment

In my Rails site, I have a model named Person, which has an ActionController and migration (database). I've inserted few rows to this table using the console (and saved them there!).
In the PersonController I have a method "list" which I want to list all the people which are in the database :

```
def list
    @persons = Person.all
end
```

However, in the list.html.erb file in the person's view, I can't access this arrey. Trying to write something like : 
<% @persons.each do |r| %>
raises an error claims that @person is nil.

I think I'm doing something wrong here. In conclusion, how can I pass a database from the controller to the view, and how can I disply it?
Thanks

Comment: Check the database and make sure the data is there.  In addition, make sure you use Person.create and not Person.new when you are creating a record via the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using to transfer data from the controller to the view is appropriate. My guess is that Person.all is not returning any results, meaning your database is not being populated via the console. Try adding your data in via seeds.rb in the db directory, and then run rake db:seed. That should do it for you. Also, generally lists of models are run through the 'index' route. I would recommend using that instead of a route 'list'.

You can also check this post to make sure you are using the console correctly:
[how to add data to database from rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489599/how-to-add-data-to-database-from-rails-console)

*****************EDIT*******************

To use index to list display a list of a model, open your routes.rb file and add the people resource to generate all routes for the person model

```
resources :people
```

That will give you index, show, edit, create, update, and destroy routes (run rake routes to see a list of all the routes). If you do not want all of those, you can use only: and except: with the resource command to limit the routes created. Example

```
resources :people, only: index
```

You then need to update your controller to match each route that you want to use. So instead of 'list' you can use index, show, edit, update, create, and destroy.

```
def index
  @people = Person.all
end
```

is an example of the index action definition. Then you just need a view to match the action, like index.html.erb. If you have any people in the database, they should now be in the @people variable during the index action and you can use that to list out each person. If you want to create some people to try it out, you can use the console, the show action you created using the resources command in the routes.rb, or use the seed.rb file and run rake db:seed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please give me example of how to write the "index" method in the controller, and for example, how can I simply disply the database in the view named index.html.erb, using a loop? I'm new to Rails and will appriciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Also, you can run a rails generator for a scaffold to generate all routes, controllers, and views for a model. Just run

    rails g scaffold person first_name:string last_name:string

or whatever you want as your model and attributes

Answer (score 0):

Your variable in controller is `@persons` and not `@person`. The error you are getting is `@person is nil`. If that is not the problem, then please remember that rails uses singular for the model name, which is `Person` and plural in other cases, `people` in naming the tables and the controllers.

If this doesn't help, please post your real filenames, and your first line of the controller along with other relevant code.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check the database and make sure the data is there.  In addition, make sure you use Person.create and not Person.new when you are creating a record via the console.

Person.new must be assigned to a variable and save must be called on that variable.  Create doesn't require that extra step

```
 u = User.new(:first => "Chris", :last => "Tilley")
 u.save! //required with new

 u = Person.create(:first => "Chris", :last => "Tilley")  //doesn't require save
```